# I want to learn how to use the different hashing, encryption/decryption algorithms in php

Tags: php, encryption, hash

I have a sample set of strings that I want to encrypt, for the password what I want is to hash it.(I made some online research but I'm a bit overwhelmed/confused with how they implement it)

I'm fairly new to security in web development, I'm currently a student and I want to learn how to create secure web applications. 
(It would be nice if you could show how I could implement hashing and encryption with my codes. *blowfish,sha256,md5*)

```
$salt = "308lk;f9vm.h-!@";

$user = "billgates@hotmail.com";

$password = "ra89232_11";
$name = "Microsoft";
$address = "Redmond, Seattle";
```

Comment: Arguably the best: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save you some hard work I'd recommend you using an already established library to do this. For example [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) or [PHP-PasswordLib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-PasswordLib)

I'm not going in more for details but instead I'd just reference you to some similar questions and possible duplicates that cover your questions.

[How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)

[Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

[Is this a secure method, oop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557440/is-this-a-secure-method-oop) (The first part)

**Encryption:** [Best way to use PHP to encrypt and decrypt passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt)